# Linking records in R with multiple, sometimes missing blocking fields

Tags: r

I have data on multiple individuals over time that I am trying to link together in `R`. The problem is that the names of individuals are often very similar yet spelled slightly differently, and ID variables are often missing (party and district are never missing but are not enough to uniquely describe individuals). Here's an example of 3 distinct individuals, all with Ennis as their last name:

```
df = structure(list(chamber = c("H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), year = c("2005", "2007", 
"1997", "1999", "2001", "1995", "1997", "1999", "2001", "2007", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2013"), name = c("Ennis", "Ennis", "Ennis, B", 
"Ennis, B", "Ennis, B", "Ennis, D", "Ennis, D", "Ennis, D", "Ennis, D", 
"Ennis", "Ennis, Bruce", "Ennis, Bruce", "Ennis, Bruce", "Ennis, J"
), party = c("100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "200", "200", 
"200", "200", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100"), district = c("028", 
"028", "028", "028", "028", "006", "006", "006", "006", "014", 
"014", "014", "014", "007"), os.id = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "DEL000009", "DEL000009", "DEL000009", NA), msp.id = c("1298", 
"1298", NA, NA, "1298", NA, NA, NA, "13676", NA, "1298", "1298", 
"1298", "567")), .Names = c("chamber", "year", "name", "party", 
"district", "os.id", "msp.id"), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which describes this example data frame:

```
   chamber year         name party district     os.id msp.id
1        H 2005        Ennis   100      028      <NA>   1298
2        H 2007        Ennis   100      028      <NA>   1298
3        H 1997     Ennis, B   100      028      <NA>   <NA>
4        H 1999     Ennis, B   100      028      <NA>   <NA>
5        H 2001     Ennis, B   100      028      <NA>   1298
6        H 1995     Ennis, D   200      006      <NA>   <NA>
7        H 1997     Ennis, D   200      006      <NA>   <NA>
8        H 1999     Ennis, D   200      006      <NA>   <NA>
9        H 2001     Ennis, D   200      006      <NA>  13676
10       S 2007        Ennis   100      014      <NA>   <NA>
11       S 2011 Ennis, Bruce   100      014 DEL000009   1298
12       S 2012 Ennis, Bruce   100      014 DEL000009   1298
13       S 2013 Ennis, Bruce   100      014 DEL000009   1298
14       S 2013     Ennis, J   100      007      <NA>    567
```

So observations 1-5 and 10-14 describe "Ennis, B", observations 6-9 describe "Ennis, D" and observation 14 describes "Ennis, J". I deduced this through piecing multiple fields together logically in my mind. Naturally I want to automate this, as I have hundreds of thousands such observations. Eventually I want to assign a unique, non-missing ID to all of these 14 observations. In this case, that would be 3 unique IDs.

I have done some research and I think the `RecordLinkage` package in R could do what I need, along with some fuzzy string matching for the names. The problem is that the blocking variables I would want to employ, which are `party`, `os.id`, and `msp.id` are not always present. That is, blocking variables need to match exactly. This is a problem, since for example observation 3 and observation 11 both describe the same person but 3 has NA for the blocking variable.

Here's the code I'm tinkering with that fails due to the missing blocking variables:

```
rpairsfuzzy <- compare.dedup(df,blockfld = c(4,6,7), strcmp = TRUE)
dim(rpairsfuzzy$pairs)
rpairsfuzzy$pairs
```

It only identifies observations 11-13 as matches since these all contain non-missing data. But clearly that's wrong.

Comment: It looks like the "party" column separates the data into what you want, no?  `split(df, df$party)` to see what I mean (on the sample data).

Comment: Are 'party' and 'district' always filled, or do these also contain missing values?

Comment: Yes, party and district are always filled. But a person's district can change over time, as you can see for Ennis, B.

Comment: @RScriv No, party doesn't in general uniquely split the records appropriately, nor in this sample data. As you can see, "Ennis, J" and "Ennis, B" are the same party, but have different msp.id.